# Need to remove content which are between two special characters in R

Tags: regex, r

My Input string is `7/31/2015` and my output string should be `7/2015`.

I am trying to use `gsub('/./','/','7/31/2015')` but not getting the correct result.

Comment: is this format specific for every input?

Comment: This? https://regex101.com/r/aK8pI6/1

Comment: `gsub('/.+/','/','7/31/2015')`..just add a `+` in your `gsub`

Comment: rock321987 and shafizadeh ur soln works..

Comment: if you're working with dates, why not `format(as.Date('7/31/2015', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%Y')`?

Comment: i can also do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are **matching only one character** with `.` in `/./`

Try with `/.+/` or `/\d+/` and replace with `/`

```
gsub('/.+/','/','7/31/2015')
```

Or

```
gsub('/\\d+/','/','7/31/2015')
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ0wT6/1)

Answer (score 2):

I will stick to your format. You have to just add a `+` in your captured string

```
 gsub('/.+/','/','7/31/2015')
```

Comment: whoever is downvoting please leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

Simply thy this:

```
/\/\d+/
```

- `\/`  matches the character `/` literally
- `\d+` one or more digit

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK8pI6/1)

---

**Full Code:**

```
gsub('/\\d+/','/','7/31/2015')
```